# PowerShell ... paste from csv to excel - as values

Tags: powershell

Team,
I've read through several existing questions covering this topic but I'm unable to get the code to work correctly.
Previous Answered Questions on Topic:

[Copy and paste excel range between workbooks in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38857994/copy-and-paste-excel-range-between-workbooks-in-powershell)

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=powershell+pastespecial

When I copy from my csv file I want to paste the data 'as values' so the formatting in my Excel file is maintained.
My existing code does not have the 'paste as values' logic included.  This code will work but it overwrites my excel formatting.

```
$pathxls = "\\servername\folderpath\Records_Inventory_${destinationfilename}.xlsx"
$pathcsv = "\\servername\folderpath\${destinationfilename}.csv"
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$Excel.visible = $false
$Workbook = $excel.Workbooks.open($pathcsv)
$Workbook2 = $excel.Workbooks.open($pathxls)
$Worksheet = $Workbook.WorkSheets.item(“Export”)
$Worksheet.activate()
$range = $WorkSheet.Range(“A1:F75”)
$range.Copy() | out-null
$Worksheet2 = $Workbook2.Worksheets.item(“Destination”)
$worksheet2.activate()
$range2 = $Worksheet2.Range(“D8”)
$Worksheet2.Paste($range2)
$workbook2.Save()
```

Can you please assist?

Comment: Did you try the `PasteSpecial` method? Did it not perform like you expected it to? `$range2.PasteSpecial('xlPasteValues')` should do exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: When I embed this snippet of code you suggested:
$range2.PasteSpecial('xlPasteValues')

I get the following error message:
Unable to get the PasteSpecial property of the Range class

Comment: Dug around and found a different site that swapped ('xlPastevalues') with $range2.PasteSpecial(-4163) -- that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to TheMadTechician for their comment above and pointing me in the right direction.

Modifying what they had suggested `$range2.PasteSpecial('xlPasteValues')` slightly to `$range2.PasteSpecial(-4163)` resolved the issue.